# Set Label From Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

Form1.vb

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Dim demoThread As Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Start As New Class1
    Me.demoThread = New Thread( _
            New ThreadStart(AddressOf Start.ThreadProcSafe))

    Me.demoThread.Start()

End Sub
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback([text] As String)
Public Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true. 
    If Me.textBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.textBox1.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Class1.vb

```
Public Class Class1

Public Sub ThreadProcSafe()
    Form1.SetText("This text was set safely.")
End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone tell me why this doesn't update the textbox?

It works when ThreadProcSafe is called when its inside Form1(and is still started by a thread) but when it's moved outside of the class into another, no warnings or errors but doesn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are referring to the default instance in your second code snippet.  Default instances are thread-specific so that second code snippet will create a new instance of the `Form1` type rather then use the existing instance.  Your `Class1` needs a reference to the original instance of `Form1`.

If that's not practical then the solution is to not do the delegation in the form but rather do it in the class accessing the form, using the `SynchronizationContext` class.

Comment: I think I got it! Need to test to see if this is thread-safe but it did work when I call the thread with a form reference and the class uses that to call the setText function.